# ClickOnce Security Zones Installation Bug

Tags: visual-studio, installation, clickonce, publishing, security-zone

I've run into a haunting bug. I've built a C# application (Visual C# 2008 Express) and have published it in the past as a ClickOnce application deployed as a zip file. I had no problem installing it on our customers' computers several months ago, but now when they attempt to install the application they get a message at startup: "Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor." When I look at the details of the message I see, "Deployment and application do not have matching security zones." Again, this problem doesn't show up when installing on my second computer, but shows up for two of our customers (again, this problem did not appear on their computers a few months ago). Because I can't replicate this problem on my own systems, this is very difficult to approach, especially as I haven't thought much of publishing settings before today. Here are some further thoughts:

-There is an app.manifest file listed under Properties in the Solution Explorer that didn't seem to be there earlier in the year. I'm not sure why this is here and whether there should be a corresponding file when I publish this.

-Sign the ClickOnce Manifests is selected.

-Enable ClickOnce Security Settings is selected

-The application is a full trust application (I toyed around with switching to a "partial trust application" and don't want to try this unless there is a high likelihood of resolving this).

-I'm looking for a fix that won't require the user to make changes on their computer. There is some evidence that clearing the oneClick cache as detailed here (http://codeketchup.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-fix-deployment-and-application.html) may work, but again that is too intensive a fix.

Thanks in advance!